Deadlock on condition variable Example
I am getting a deadlock I can't explain with the below code. I expected that the code should work because of the spurious wake-up but I think I am missing something. I checked this Condition variable deadlock but no luck.
class SafeQueue
{
private:
    std::queue<int> data_queue;
    mutable std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::atomic<bool> flag{ true }; // Atomic flag to control the queue

public:
    void push(int val)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
        data_queue.push(val);
        cv.notify_one(); // Notify waiting thread upon pushing data
    }

    bool pop(int& val)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
        cv.wait(lock, [this]() { return !data_queue.empty() || !flag; }); // Wait until queue is not empty or flag is turned off

        if (!flag && data_queue.empty())
        {
            return false; // Queue is empty and flag is off, return false to indicate termination
        }

        if (!data_queue.empty())
        {
            val = data_queue.front();
            data_queue.pop();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    void turnOff()
    {
        flag = false;
    }

    bool isFlagOn() const
    {
        return flag;
    }
};

void consumerLoop(SafeQueue& q)
{
    while (q.isFlagOn())
    {
        int val;
        if (q.pop(val))
        {
            std::cout << "Consumed: " << val << std::endl;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Consumer exiting" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    SafeQueue q;
    std::thread consumerThread(consumerLoop, std::ref(q));

    // Producer pushes some values into the queue
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        q.push(i);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }

    // Turn off the queue flag
    q.turnOff();

    consumerThread.join();

    return 0;
}

Can you please help point out where it happens and how to correct the implementation? Any other suggestions for implementation are welcome (I need a deque I just included the example for queue for simplicity)

"I expected that the code should work because of the spurious wake-up" - Eh? Spurious wake-up is not the thing which one should rely upon when write the code. While calling turnOff makes the condition in cv.wait to become true, the consumer is NOT awaken. It is awaken only when notify is called, but you don't call notify in that case.

Thanks so much! This means relying on the spurious wake-up is wrong code? I think I don't understand how spurious wake-up works. I thought the cv will notify itself if the condition is true inside the wait predicat at the spurious wake-up. Is the deadlock explained by the fact the spurious wake-up never happens please?

Yes it's wrong to rely on spurious wakeups in that way. They might happen and might not happen (and your code must cope with both cases).

Actually, "they...might not happen" is a pretty weak statement. The truth is, they almost never happen except under certain special circumstances, and on some operating systems, they absolutely never will happen.

Amazing! All clear now, thanks so much all!

Your consumerThread is hanging on cv.wait and only waking up when push does a cv.notify_one(). This happens 10 times, then the producer loop is done and flag is turned off - however consumerThread is still/again hanging on cv.wait.
At this point your consumerThread is stuck until either:

Somebody calls cv.notify_one() (or cv.notify_all())
You get a spurious wakeup - but do remember that these are mostly defects that you may get from various real-world conditions (this is why you need to code as if they might happen), but that they are not supposed to happen.
You terminate the program

A fairly simple solution in this case is to do this:
void turnOff()
{
    flag = false;
    cv.notify_one();
}

